# Read hex characters from an ini file

Tags: c++, char, c++builder, ini

I have an ini file with some hex characters,like this:

```
[FOO]
1=0x55
2=0x40
3=0x90
```

First, is this the right format for an ini file, or should i use \x50?

Second, how can i read the characters? i have this:

```
char Frame[4]
TIniFile* IniFile;
IniFile=new TIniFile(cPath+"\\"+"setup.ini");
for( int i = 1; i < 4; i++ )
{
 Frame[i]=IniFile->ReadString("FOO",i,-1); 
}
```

The problem is that IniFile->ReadChar doesn't exist (i am using borland c++ builder 6).

how can i cast the string (0x55 for example) to a char? so i can put it in the *Frame* array

Comment: "First, is this the right format for an ini file, or should i use \x50?" there's no standard specification for INI files, so you may do as it's simpler for your parser (although, 0x50 is more widely used for numbers).

Answer (score 1):

The `\x55` notation is typically used within string literals:

```
const char* s = "\x55";
```

When writing to a file `0x55` is common, but ultimately it is up to the code processing the file to know what it is consuming.

I cannot comment on `IniFile` but if you can manage to store the value into a `char[]` you can use [`std::strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) to obtain the integer value:

```
const char* s = "0x55";
long value = std::strtol(s, 0, 16);
```

<strike>Also, note that the `for` loop is going beyond the bounds of array `Frame` as array indexes are zero based. The valid indexes for `Frame` are `0`, `1` and `2` only but the loop would access `3` which is undefined behaviour. Change to:
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)</strike>

Note the `for` loop will not populate the first element of `Frame`, as array indexes are zero based (unsure if that is intentional).

Comment: Ok i now can read in the hex value like a string. so i got: str="0x55". how can i make this a (hex)char? the std::strtol(str, 0, 16); doesn't work, i can't do: 'Frame[i]=std::strtol(str,0,16);. compiler gives error that the function returns a AnsiString...

Comment: @Marty, `IniFile->ReadString` sounds promising.

Comment: @Marty, `strtol()` does *not* return a string, it returns a `long`. To store it as a `char`, cast it: `static_cast<char>(strtol(....));`

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
AnsiString string;
TIniFile* IniFile;
IniFile=new TIniFile(cPath+"\\"+"setup.ini");
for( int i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
{
 string=IniFile->ReadString("FOO",i,-1);
 Frame[i]=static_cast<char>(std::strtol(string.c_str(), 0, 16));
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(str,string.c_str());` corrupts memory

Comment: How about `Frame[i]=static_cast<char>(std::strtol(string.c_str(), 0, 16));`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the VCL, you can use the `StrToInt...()` family of functions, which support `0xXX` notation in C++, and then cast the result to `char`, eg:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    Frame[i] = (char) StrToIntDef(IniFile->ReadString("FOO", i+1, ""), -1);
}
```

Or:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    Frame[i] = (char) IniFile->ReadString("FOO", i+1, "").ToIntDef(-1);
}
```